# Are there any reasons why one should not enable AWS Compute Optimizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Based on their documentation, it's free.

> There is no additional charge for Compute Optimizer. EC2 instance type and EC2 Auto Scaling group configuration recommendations are available for free. You pay only for the AWS Compute resources needed to run your applications and Amazon CloudWatch monitoring fees.

Being free and potentially can lower cost, I fail to see the downside of it.

And since the feature is not enabled by default, there must be reasons why one should not enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot think of a reason to not opt-in for the service, it is NOT totally free, and costs $0.0003360215 resource/hour based on the number of hours a resource is running per month. This should, however, be much lesser a price to be paid for the savings it can potentially offer in most cases.

[image]

Do make sure to check the official page for the latest pricing - https://aws.amazon.com/compute-optimizer/pricing/